# how to get array item from ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am  trying to get the item of array on click when I am working with the reverse array. but getting the wrong index values.

when I clicked on `[7] Sebastian who is 50 years old

```
<button ng-click="show_id($index)">get my id</button>
```

I want alert value should be 7 not 0 but it alerts 0

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>



  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>


<script>
angular.module("my_app",[])
.controller("my_ctr",function($scope){

    $scope.show_id=function(index){
        alert(index);
    }
})
</script>

</head>
<body ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="my_ctr">
    <div ng-init="friends = [
    {id:1, name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {id:2, name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {id:3, name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {id:4, name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {id:5, name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {id:6, name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {id:7, name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},

  ]">
    I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:

    <ul>
      <li  ng-repeat="friend in friends.slice().reverse() ">
        [{{friend.id}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
        <button ng-click="show_id($index)">get my id</button>

      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to do edit and update that particular record how can I do that?

Comment: When that button is clicked, do you want to alert the `id` value of that friend? So, `7` for `"Sebastian"`, `3` for `"Johanna"`, `5` for `"Mary"` etc?

Comment: yes...but not only alert but i want to do operation like edit and update. But did not get the solution.

Comment: Edit functionality is a bit too broad for an answer on here. I'd suggest you take a look at a tutorial like this: http://angular.codeschool.com/

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: that's not how angular works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for the `id` of the "current friend", just use the `id` provided in your object:

Replace:

```
<button ng-click="show_id($index)">get my id</button>
```

With:

```
<button ng-click="show_id(friend.id)">get my id</button>
```

Comment: id can be different from index.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: Look at what the button is supposed to do: _"get my id"_. This does __exactly that__ The whole array index was the wrong way to go about it. Even the desired output value of `7` refrects the `id`, and has __nothing__ to do with the element's index.

Comment: On stack overflow, the OP isn't always right in how he goes about fixing a problem. You'd think someone with 13k rep would have learned that by now.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: [He wants the `Id`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911673/how-to-get-original-index-array-value-when-using-array-reverse-in-anguler-js?noredirect=1#comment40559289_25911673). Please remove that downvote.

Comment: Edit __what__? I was right to use `friend.id`, my answer isn't incorrect in any way. -.-

Comment: I should point out that the answer that **works** will be the one the user accepts - if they do so at all.

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed: have you _ever_ worked with angular? The only thing needed is the current friend's model. Better known as `friend`, here.

Comment: `show_id(friend.id)` was in my answer from the moment the answer was posted. Did you even read my answer?

Answer (score -1):

As you are iterating on the reverse of the list, you cannot get the index of original list

to get that you need to use the below

```
ng-click="show_id(friends.length-$index)"
```